# Inputtextarea not showing text

Tags: java, jsf-2

I seem to have an issue with the jsf components inputText and inputTextarea. They do not  show the value that my backend holds. I am 100% certain that the backend has those values and I even tried outputting it with an outputLabel and the outputlabel shows the value the outputTexts didn't want to show.

My Jsf page:

```
[...]
<h:form rendered="#{gvpController.logInBean.gvpView}">
    <fieldset>
        <h3>Wijzig een titel</h3>
        <label>
            <span>Titel:</span>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{faseController.selectedFase.parent_id}" valueChangeListener="#{faseController.prepareEditView}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{faseController.fasesAsSelectItems}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu><br />
        </label>
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{faseController.selectedFase.titel}" />
        <br />
        <ui:repeat value="#{faseController.selectedFase.subItems}" var="subfase">
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{subfase.titel}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
[...]
```

The odd thing is that it's only the first outputTextarea that isn't showing its value. The outputTextarea's inside the ui:repeat show the correct values.

Thanks.

Comment: Is "outputTexts" and "outputTextarea" typos? You mean to say "inputTexts" and "inputTextarea", correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found *a* solution. I'm not sure if it's a good one or if it could be done in another way, if you know, please let me know, but here's how I fixed it:

My JSF page:

```
[...]
<h:form id="editform" rendered="#{gvpController.logInBean.gvpView}">
    <fieldset>
        <h3>Wijzig een titel</h3>
        <label>
            <span>Titel:</span>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{faseController.selectedFase.parent_id}" valueChangeListener="#{faseController.prepareEditView}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{faseController.fasesAsSelectItems}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu><br />
        </label>
        <h:inputTextarea id="textboxParent" value="#{faseController.selectedFase.titel}" />
        <br />
        <ui:repeat value="#{faseController.selectedFase.subItems}" var="subfase">
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{subfase.titel}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
[...]
```

I added id's to the form and the textbox that was acting up. And then I added the following piece of code in #{faseController.prepareEditView} :

```
[...]
UIInput input = (UIInput) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("editform:textBoxParent");
input.setValue(selectedFase.getTitel());
input.setSubmittedValue(null);
[...]
```

This forced the inputtextarea to display the text I wanted.

Comment: I have been fighting a similar issue for 4hrs.  This fixed it immediately.  Thank you!  That said, I think its CRAZY that I have to do this.

Comment: I don't remember why this happened or why I had to apply this crazy workaround and I haven't checked if it is fixed in later versions, but it's cool that my ancient comment has been a help to you! :)